# not able to access apache from local machine, though it runs on the vagrant

Tags: apache, vagrant

I installed vagrant box in mac system. In that vagrant box I configured apache and it is running. I am trying to access it from my machine, but I am not able to access.

```rb
*Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "oar-team/debian8"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8000

  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", id: "vagrant-root", 
  owner: "vagrant", group: "www-data", mount_options: 
  ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]   

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.define "127.0.0.1"

end*
```

Above one is my vagrant file. I am vagrant up and it is running the vagrant box.

Comment: What are you trying to access the server?

Comment: I have hosted my site on vagrant machine. I want to access it from my local

Comment: I understand the question. I asked how you have tried to access the virtual machine. What IP address?

Comment: I assigned a port for vagrant as 8000. I am accessing with http://localhost:8000

Comment: Please show your vagrantfile. Vagrant doesn't port forward by default

Comment: I assigned the port by using 
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8000

Comment: It would be useful for you to [edit] your question to include the contents of the vagrantfile.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer finally. After running the **vagrant up** 
My site has some set of scripts to run. To run those scripts I need to run 
**vagrant provision**. then only it is running the site.